# Patching a collection to sql, appending rows, I need to update

Tags: sql-server, collections, patch, powerapps, power-automate

I have a SQL Server table `csv_data_tbl`, and a collection `colCommon` which is collected at the beginning from the same table.

A gallery allows users to modify the collection using input text fields. I want to patch this modified collection to same SQL Server table.

I am using a button with following `onSelect` code:

```
Patch(CSV_DATA_TBL, colCommon)
```

But it is appending the records to the SQL Server table, so I get duplicate records with user modified data.

Is there any better solution there to update the SQL Server table from my collection?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [ForAll function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-forall) which will loop through all of the items in your collection, and send the updates to the database using the [Patch function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-patch). For example, if your table `csv_data_tbl` has a primary key column called 'ID', and the user can update the columns 'Field1' and 'Field2', you can use an expression like the following:

```
ForAll(
    colCommon As coll,
    Patch(
        CSV_DATA_TBL,
        { ID: coll.ID }, // (*)
        {
            Field1: colCommon.Field1,
            Field2: colCommon.Field2
        }))
```

(*) Typically we would need a full record to be updated as the second parameter of the Patch function - but in the case of a SQL Server table, all we need is the primary key, and it will be able to match it. If you were to retrieve the entire record, the second parameter would be something like `LookUp(CSV_DATA_TBL, ID = coll.ID)`.

Comment: Thank you So much @carlosfigueira, your code helped me.